# Product details are not available on WooCommerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, echo, product

I have the following code that I'm using to display a modal containing some of the information from the current product page:

```php
function visualizer_modal() {
    if(!is_product()) {
        return;
    }
    global $product;
    ?>
    <div class="visualizer-modal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Customize & Buy</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <img
                src="<?php wp_get_attachment_url($product->get_id()) ?>" 
                alt="<?php $product->get_name() ?> image" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

It's being called from the function that creates the button using this line:

```
add_action('wp_footer', [$this, 'visualizer_modal']);
```

However, I'm not getting any product information coming through. I only get the broken image icon and the word "image" from the `alt` attribute. I previously tried using `print_footer_scripts` instead of `wp_footer`, but I got the same result. I also used `wp_get_attachment_image_src` to try getting the product image, but that didn't work either, nor would it explain why I'm not getting the product name in `alt`.

I'm fairly new to developing for WordPress and WooCommerce both, so I'm not sure why `$product` isn't giving me anything. Is it because I'm calling this from the page's footer after the product template? Or is there something else happening here?

Note: for the code block above, I have the `img` tag all on one line, I just broke it up here to make it a bit more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many mistakes in your code:

- `wp_get_attachment_url()` requires the image attachment ID, not the product ID, so you will use `$product->get_image_id()` for that purpose.
- You need to use `echo` with `wp_get_attachment_url()` and `$product->get_name()` to get something displayed.
- Instead of `wp_get_attachment_url()` you can use directly `$product->get_image()`.

Try the following:

```
function visualizer_modal() {
    if( ! is_product() ) return;
    global $product;
    ?>
    <div class="visualizer-modal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><?php _e('Customize & Buy'); ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <?php echo $product->get_image('full', ['alt' => $product->get_name().' image']); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action('wp_footer', [$this, 'visualizer_modal']);
```

It should work.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I have a lot still to learn about this stuff, and I greatly appreciate your help. :)